# Parse command to CMD from VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to parse the command `echo msg>com4` to CMD from web application. I was tried different ways but I am not able  to do it. In this case I want to show the results also without popping CMD run and close it.

Here is my script:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/Vbscript"> 
Function cmdRun( )
    Dim shell, fileName
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set proc = shell.Exec("echo msg>com4")
End Function
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="cmdRun()" value="copy" />
</body>
</html>
```

Sometimes it is showing error "VBA Script 424: object required". When I used cscript that also shows the error.

Comment: The code you posted would not have raised the error you claim it does. Please create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem you're facing, then [edit] your question and post *that* code along with the complete, unaltered error *that* code raised. Copy/paste. Post a screenshot of the error message if you can't copy/paste it as text. Do not paraphrase. Do not type from memory.

Comment: Also, running `echo msg>com4` is not going to work, b/c both `echo` and the redirection operator are CMD-builtin features that aren't available outside of CMD.

Comment: There is no such thing as a VBA Script Error, please copy errors correctly to avoid typos if entered manually. The error is a VBScript Error, a very common one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running as a web application, ie with a page open from the internet, you man not run programs or use activex controls that can affect the system.

On a web page usesafesubset is true.

See my answer here - [What can't I use when UseSafeSubset is true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064164/what-cant-i-use-when-usesafesubset-is-true)

Also VBScript no longer works on web pages. Only on local pages and intranet sites.

If you change your script to a local VBS file and run it with CScript.exe  and use `wscript.echo` to print.

```
cmd /c cscript //nologo MyVbs.vbs > Com4
```